# 403 error on installed codeigniter on godaddy subdomain

Tags: wordpress, codeigniter

I have a Wordpress on a main domain which works fine but just installed CodeIgniter 3 on a subdomain and I keep getting Additionally, a 403 Forbidden error on CodeIgniter. I have played around with `.htaccess` with no success. Here is my `.htaccess` as it now

```
RewriteEngine On
#RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f  
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d  
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?/$1 [L]
```

Answer (score 0):

Did you try deleting the .htaccess in application folder?

You can try pasting this in your principal .htaccess

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php [L]
```

This htacces only will work if your remove the /index.php/ from your url's

Comment: Did not work, mind you the CodeIgniter is on subdomain on different directory

Comment: that does not should represent any problem because for the server and would be like a domain